# MySQL Filter for Vicidial

Tags: php, mysql

I work for a call center doing tech support, our Dialer uses filters that are written in MySQL. I am a complete novice and cannot wrap my head around it no matter how many tutorials I try.

The only example I can find in the manual is:

```
called count >= 7
```

This will only call leads with 7 or greater attempts.

The above syntax redacts the `SELECT` and `WHERE` statements because apparently the filter is merely a `WHERE` statement appended to the standard query.

We have a field called entry_date it is in the format of `11/17/2015  9:48:16 AM` (as are all our date entries) I am attempting to filter by results greater than 30 days from the current date.

I tried

```
entry_date - NOW() >= 30
```

And it doesn't work :(

Any assistance would be most appreciated.

Ryan

Comment: `11/17/2015 9:48:16 AM` is not a valid datetime format, so you need to covert it first before trying to manipulate it - see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 2):

Here is a real example of a `VICIdial` filter that is used to prevent `NI(Not Interested)` status leads from being `dialed` within 30 days of their last call:

```
( ( (status='NI') and (last_local_call_time < CONCAT(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -30 DAY),' ',CURTIME()) ) ) or (status != 'NI') )
```

Answer (score 1):

You may have an issue with your date format if it is stored in the database as you indicate. The following will select within the last 30 days if `entry_date` is a datetime field.

```
entry_date > NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY
```

Answer (score 1):

yes, well, the mysql date functions are a bit bizarre.  Here is the way to compute the date 30 days in the past:

```
mysql> select DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 day) as past;
+------------+
| past       |
+------------+
| 2015-10-20 |
+------------+
```

and I guess you will need to convert the timestamp of your `entry_date` field to just a plain date without the time, something like this:

```
DATE(entry_date)
```

so then I would guess that to get all records older than 30 days would be:

```
DATE(entry_date) < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 day)
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Sean, MySQL datetime format is yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss
so you will first have to conver your datetime MySQL datetime using [STR_TO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function

```
STR_TO_DATE(entry_date, '%Y-%m-%d');
```

then using [DATE_SUB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub) function you can find last 30 days from current date

```
DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

So, your condition would be

```
STR_TO_DATE(entry_date, 'Y-m-d') < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

Please see [MySQL Date and Time Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) for further reference.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call a number that was not called in last 30 days then try.

```
last_local_call_time < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```